# Adding keys to dict with tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key

I have a tuple as follows:

```
tuple
{('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')}
```

I would like to create a dict and want to set its keys as the above tuple.
Dictionary should look like following:

```
dict
{('A', 'B'): None,
 ('A', 'C'): None,
 ('B', 'C'): None}
```

How would I do it as easy as possible?

I tried this but does not work:

```
dict = {(set(tuple(sorted(x)): None for x in lines_tuple)}
```

Comment: 1. You have a set of tuples, not a tuple. 2. How have you tried to solve this?

Comment: @DeepSpace this was my approach check question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict` has a `fromkeys` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys), which defaults the values to `None` if you don't pass any in:

```
original = {('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')}
new = dict.fromkeys(original)
```

`new` should now look like `{('A', 'B'): None, ('B', 'C'): None, ('A', 'C'): None}`

Comment: works ty, need to wait 6mins for accept